# Trying to figure out why my foreach import doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, foreach

I've on my view:

```
@foreach($cart_item->where('shopping_cart_id','37') as $cart) 

 <li class="clearfix">{{$cart->prize_id}}</li>

@endforeach
```

Can somebody help me figure out whats wrong with my foreach loop?

I have come down to just trying to basically displaying the id's but its giving me an php error.

"Undefined variable cart_item", but I did define the variable on the cart controller as so:

```
$cart_item = ShoppingCartItem::where('shopping_cart_id',$cookie->cart_id)->where('prize_id',$_POST['prize_id'])->first();
```

Comment: BTW: Don't use this type of logic in the view.

Comment: Because at first you get ->first() and after that try use ->where() statement

Comment: If all other suggestions didn't work, and you have passed the variable to your view already, then try `dd($cart_item)` at the beginning of your view. What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should do like this

```
$cart_item = ShoppingCartItem::where('shopping_cart_id',$cookie->cart_id)->where('prize_id',$_POST['prize_id'])where('shopping_cart_id','37')->get();
```

and after that use it in your view

```
@foreach($cart_item as $cart) 

 <li class="clearfix">{{$cart->prize_id}}</li>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question, the solution is to pass `$cart_item` to your view.

Once that is done, you can just do the following:

```
@foreach($cart_item as $cart)
```

What you are currently doing is not the recommended way of doing it. This logic should be in your Controller and not your View.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass that variable to the view.
I guess it's Laravel so just when calling your view add it to the comapct function

```
view('viewname', compact('cart_item'))
```

And like other suggested don't do it that way, it's better do define a scope function in that model that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

At first you are adding controller logic on a view, and that is really a bad practice.

Your problem looks like on your controller line:

```
$cart_item = ShoppingCartItem::where('shopping_cart_id',$cookie->cart_id)->where('prize_id',$_POST['prize_id'])->first();
```

Is returning NULL, it means the ShoppingCartItem is not found on your query or you are just not sending the variable to the view.

In your view you can control if the $cart_item variable exists like this:

```
@if(isset($cart_item))
  @foreach($cart_item->where('shopping_cart_id','37') as $cart) 

   <li class="clearfix">{{$cart->prize_id}}</li>

 @endforeach
@endif
```

This will prevent future errors in case the $cart_item variable is not set.